# How do i send mouse click to a different app

Tags: window, click, mouse

I'm trying so send mouse click to calculator app but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int window = FindWindow(null, "Calculator");
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PostMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 50, 50);
        PostMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONUP, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you click the mouse for real, it probably posts the message to *the button*, not the calculator window.

Comment: I've also tried putting it on a timer

Comment: You can use Spy++ to see what message is sent when you click on the calculator (probably you have the right message but you are sending it to the wrong window) and then send that. Or you can use SendInput to simulate real mouse clicks on the screen (so the system figures out which window is underneath the cursor)

Comment: How can i see it in spy++?